Maven exception to upload artifacts to Nexus : Connection reset error
Here my Gitlab job is failing with the below error logs for quite some time now and I unable to give it a permanent solution. Retrying the job will fix it at times, but not everytime. Below are the error logs from the gitlab job.
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-deploy-plugin:2.7:deploy-file (default-cli) on project frontend: Failed to deploy artifacts: Could not transfer artifact frontend:war:2.1.118665 from/to nexus.xxx.com (https://nexus.xxx.com/repository/maven-releases): Connection reset -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-deploy-plugin:2.7:deploy-file (default-cli) on project frontend: Failed to deploy artifacts: Could not transfer artifact frontend:war:2.1.118665 from/to nexus.xxx.com (https://nexus.xxx.com/repository/maven-releases): Connection reset
This behavior would fix it self on rerun of the Job. Or restarting docker on the gitlab runner has helped us as a work around for this issue.
expecting a permanent fix for this problem as the work around also seems to fail at times.

Are you using gitlab runners?
